# Return a dataframe from R to a shell script as a variable

Tags: r, linux, bash, shell

I am writing a shell script which contains commands to run series of R scripts. These R scripts are interlinked as, the first R script should return a dataframe to shell script variable and I want to pass that variable to second R script.
I tried doing this by using `cat` function in first Rscript. This handles strings and numbers but not dataframes. I want to return and pass dataframes. Is there any way that I could do this.
Below is the sample R scripts and shell script.

Here is my shell script: shell1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

v1=$(R --slave --no-save < DataExtraction.R)
v2=$(R --slave --no-save < DataTransformation.R $v1)
echo $v2
```

DataExtraction.R:

```
df1 <- mtcars
cat(df1)
```

DataTransformation.R:

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
df2 <-args[1]
abc <- df2$mpg
cat(abc)
```

when I run the shell script I should see the content of mtcars$mpg printed on the terminal.

Comment: Why not have `DataExtraction.R` write `df1` to a CSV file, and have `DataTransformation.R` read that file back in? Bash has no concept of a `data.frame` so you can't expect to pass your object between scripts like that.

Comment: @nrussell. Thanks, I am currently doing the same, writing to a csv and then reading  it. Just wanted to know if there is any work around.

Comment: I think writing to / reading from disk is the simplest approach here, even if it seems a little circuitous, only because there is no built-in representation of the `data.frame` type (or any table-like object) in `bash` / `sh` / et al. If you were transferring a single integer / double / string, that would be a different story. Personally I would most likely return the name of the file written to in the first script like you are doing here: `v1=$(R --slave --no-save < DataExtraction.R)`.